# Не запускается установленный apk файл на более старых устройствах android

Tags: unity3d, apk

Я воспользовался устройством Lenovo 916A с версией Android 5.0 для того, чтобы протестировать приложение созданное на Unity. По каким-то причинам приложение не запускается. Позже я воспользовался телефоном Redmi 7 и эмулятором Nox версии 6.6.1.1, все работает отлично, без всяких конфликтов. Еще в году эдак 2017, если не ошибаюсь, таких проблем не возникало. Перерыл множество форумов, никак не могу решить проблему. Unity версию использую 2019.4.16f. Надеюсь все данные предоставленные мной, помогут вам решить мою проблему, любая помощь приветствуется.

Информация о телефоне

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прилагаю изображения настроек Build Setting и Player Setting... -> Other Settings

[image: Build Settings]

[image: Other Settings 1]

[image: Other Setti]

Comment: было бы прекрасно прикрепить еще и информацию о билде операционки на Lenovo 916A - там есть отдельно версия операционки, и отдельно версия ядра. Нужно прикрепить скриншот что бы было видно обе версии.

Comment: Я добавил изображение об информации по телефону, но версию ядра я не могу найти. В интернете нашел информацию о том какую ОС предустанавливают по умолчанию: Предустановленная ОС: 
Android 4.4.2. Больше к сожалению ничего не нашел.

Comment: нужен скриншот с конкретного телефона.

Comment: Листните пожалуйста выше, я правил свой вопрос, добавил скриншот с телефона. Извините меня, если я не могу понять о чем вы говорите.

Comment: а при изменении билда с андроида с АПИ 19 версии на 21 меняется что-то? (с андроид 4.4 на 5.0) ? На телефоне начинает запускаться? А если поменять версию таргет билда?

Comment: Сначала поменял Minimum API Level на Anroid 5.0, Target API оставил так же на 30. Пишет: "В приложении произошла ошибка". Решил поменять Target API на 21, а Minimum API Level поставить на 19, ошибка та же.

Comment: там должны быть детали ошибки где-то. Если нету то в логах системы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Не знаю почему, но для меня сработало именно это решение:**

1. Экспортируйте свой проект в любую папку. Для этого перейдите в меню Assets -> Export Package...
2. Создайте новый (чистый) проект в Unity Hub.
3. Как откроется новый проект, импортируйте весь ранее экспортируемый проект. Перейдите в меню Assets -> Import Package -> Custom Package...
4. При сборки проекта не забудьте выставить все параметры вновь, ибо все настройки сбросятся по умолчанию.